# Why my app crash when I add ImageView to a CardView or fragment?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception, android-imageview, android-cardview

I'm trying to make a CardView like the twitter ones to use it with a RecyclerView.
The CardView without ImageView works well, but when I add ImageView the app gives me a NullPointerException

This is the **code** of the CardView without the ImageView (**Works well**) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/twoot_cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/twootUserImg"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/user_round" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/twootContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/twootUserImg"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/twootUserImg">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/twootUserName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="UserName"
                    android:textColor="#404040"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/twootUserTwoot"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="This is a sample Twoot" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/twootUserRetwoot"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="8" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/twootUserLike"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="15" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This is the **code** CardView with the ImageView of the like and retweet (**Doesn't work**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/twoot_cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/twootUserImg"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/user_round" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/twootContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/twootUserImg"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/twootUserImg">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/twootUserName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/username"
                    android:textColor="#404040"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/twootUserTwoot"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="This is a sample Twoot" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/retwoot" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/twootUserRetwoot"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="8" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/heart" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/twootUserLike"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="15" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The **error** that I get is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.twittor, PID: 13755
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.twittor.LoginActivity.Next(LoginActivity.java:32)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**Attempts:**

I've tried to use smaller photos or add the ImageView on other label, but both doesn't work

The LoginActivity.java is the activity before the activity that contains the RecyclerView

I've also tried to add the image on the fragment that contains the RecyclerView (The app also crash with that)

Comment: Your crash is from trying to access an `EditText` variable or field, and it is `null`. There is no `EditText` in your layout, so if you are trying to retrieve an `EditText` from there, that is why it is coming back as `null`. Beyond that, your [mcve] really should include `LoginActivity`, at least enough to see this `Next()` method and where this `EditText` is supposed to be coming from.

Comment: The thing is that the EditText is on the previous activity, like the Next() method (That method takes the login data and change to the next activity with Intent and putExtra), I don't know why if i add an ImageView to the fragment or RecyclerView the error happend on the previous activity

Answer (score 0):

Finally I change the id from ImageViewX to other id like "like" or "retwoot", now i receive an "ID does not reference a View inside this Activity" error on the Navigation Drawer Activity